# Elements get 'pulled' into paragraph

Tags: html, css, css-float, paragraph

While adding some CSS to my HTML I stumbled across this weird behaviour, as seen on the screenshot:
[Screenshot in Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WCilk.png).
I was wondering if someone could explain to me why this happens everytime I make my button float left (in CSS).

My code:

```css
body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

/* Classes */
.smallButton {
    /* Button */
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 15px;
    outline: none;
}

.largeButton {
    /* Button */
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 30px;
    outline: none;
}

/* Individuals */
#toolList {
    float: left;
    vertical-align: top;
}

#bmenuButton {
    float: left;
}

#textField {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    
    <head>
        <title>Stackoverflow</title>
        <!-- Stylesheets -->
        <link type="text/css", href="css/styles.css", rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <div id="toolList">
            
            <!-- Sidebar button -->
            <button id="bmenuButton" class="largeButton">BurgerMenu Button</button>
            
            <!-- Toolbar A -->
            <div id="toolBarA">
                <!--1st line -->
                <div id="toolLineA">
                    <!-- Fonts --> 
                    <select>
                        <option value="Times New Roman">Times New Roman</option>
                        <option value="Arial">Arial</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <!--2nd line -->
                <div id="toolLineB">
                    <!-- Formatting -->
                    <button class="smallButton">Bold</button>
                    <button class="smallButton">Italic</button>
                    <button class="smallButton">Underline</button>
                    <button class="smallButton">Crossthrough</button>
                    <!-- Alignments -->
                    <button class="smallButton">Left</button>
                    <button class="smallButton">Center</button>
                    <button class="smallButton">Right</button>
                    <!-- Utility -->
                    <button class="smallButton" disabled>Undo</button>
                    <button class="smallButton" disabled>Redo</button>
                    <!-- Document -->
                    <button class="smallButton">Print</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            
        </div>     
        
        <!-- Text field -->
        <p id="textField", contenteditable="true">Contenteditable paragraph text</p>
    </body>
    
</html>
```

Could somebody please explain to me why this happens scince I am fairly new to web development?

Comment: hard to know without a working example and a screenshot without annotations

Comment: I am working on an example that runs in the browser. Please wait a sec

Comment: What is the 'weird behavior' that you're experiencing?

Comment: The other html elements get 'pulled' into the paragraph. I would expect them to be outside though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it RE: 'The other html elements get 'pulled' into the paragraph. I would expect them to be outside though.'

Your paragraph is just sitting inline with your floated elements. You need to clear your float in order to make the paragraph sit below. To do this, wrap your paragraph in a div (class called 'clearfloat') and then add the css 'clear' property with value 'both' to the div.

HTML:

```
<div class="clearfloat">
<p id="textField", contenteditable="true">Contenteditable paragraph text</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.clearfloat { 
clear:both;
}
```